# psycopg2 - datetime SyntaxError: syntax error at or near x

Tags: python, psycopg2

I got this kind of error message when trying to insert datetime format

```
pmd_modified_date_time = json_data['pmd:symbol']['pmd:dataPoint'][x]['pmd:modifiedDateTime']

cur.execute("INSERT INTO daily_price (pmd_modified_date_time) VALUES ("+pmd_modified_date_time+")")
```

Error message

```
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "11"
LINE 1: ...latest) VALUES (2011-11-01 11:14:43,2...
                                       ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enclose the date string in quotes:

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO daily_price (pmd_modified_date_time) VALUES ('"+pmd_modified_date_time+"')")
```

(Note the new single quotes)

Comment: Im getting new error message 

InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer and ask a new question providing some more of your code.

Comment: its related to your answer actually.